# I am trying to write a trigger when the record is shared for this object with any user.

Tags: apex, sharerecord

I have a custom object myObj. I am trying to write a trigger when the record is shared for this object with any user. Salesforce creates myObj__Share object for sharing. I can see when I share a record to any user, myObj__Share is updated with a new row for access level for the user. I like to execute a trigger or capture the post save event when any record is share for myObj with any user.
Is there anyway to execute or write an apex after a record is shared for any customer object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write trigger on the share objects. This is not allowed as now.

There are 2 solution that I think you can implement:

**1)Custom Button:** Replace the standard share button from the page layout with a custom button. Use this button to add / remove shares, you can insert share records from APEX. And when a new record is inserted, you run your code. But sharing may happen from other parts of code, so this solution is not 100% accurate.

**2)Schedule Class** Run a schedule job in very small intervals, check if there are new share records inserted into the system and then run your code. This is 100% guaranteed to cover all the records but this will not be real-time. So in case you want some immediate action like updating a field then it may become an issue.